# SCCM 2012 R2 not registering clients. ApprovalStatus of -1

Tags: windows, sccm, sccm-2012, system-center

We are experiencing an issue with SCCM 2012 R2 when a client attempts to register within the DB. The MP_RegistrationManager log is reporting an ApprovalStatus of -1

```
<![LOG[Mp Reg: Reply message <ClientRegistrationResponse ResponseType="Confirmation" TimeStamp="2015-02-12T14:25:07Z" Status="1" ApprovalStatus="-1"/>
```

Does anyone know what an ApprovalStatus of -1 means? I know we should normally expect a 0 or a 1.

UPDATE: So after reviewing more logs, I think we've found a potential problem, the client attempts to register with one GUID, but then during the DB write, it uses a different GUID. We're tracing down some potential cert issues. –  Andrew 2 days ago

Comment: How are your site approval settings (for new clients) configured? (Manual or automatic?)  I believe that's what the Approval Status is referencing, but I can't find a source for that right now... which is kind of baffling.

Comment: So after reviewing more logs, I think we've found a potential problem, the client attempts to register with one GUID, but then during the DB write, it uses a different GUID. We're tracing down some potential cert issues.

Comment: Andrew, welcome to ServerFault. You should add that progress to your initial question, so that others can find it and offer assistance.